# How to write a C++ stdlib style increment function for use in algorithms

Tags: c++, std

I am experimenting with the C++ standard library and wanted to write a generic increment operator for practice.  Here is my attempt below.  Is there a much easier way?  I wanted it to operate a bit like std::plus.  But I cannot use plus because it is a binary operator and generate_n requires a function with no arguments.

Here is my attempt.  Any feedback would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


template<typename T>
class incr {
public:
    incr(const T& startnum = 0) : m_start(startnum) {}

    T operator()() { return m_start++; }

private:
    T m_start;
};

void printme(int i) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}

int main() {
    int n = 10;
    std::vector<int> sq(n);
    incr<int> i(3);
    std::generate_n(sq.begin(), n, i);
    std::for_each(sq.begin(), sq.end(), printme);
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:
In order to support a wide range of platforms I need to exclude C++11 and Boost.

Comment: Have you considered [std::iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)?

Comment: @GrigoriyChudnov I need to exclude support for C++11 - see update to question.  But interesting C++11 includes this.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [operator overloading](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/)?

Comment: You mean overload operator() for plus?